# Camera not showing up on device while testing QRcode in device objective c

Tags: ios

hello there I am working on this app where I am working on **QR Code**. I have implemented the code but thing is when I am **testing** the app on my device it goes to the `view controller` where **QR** is implemented but **camera** does **not** show up. I have set camera permission in `info.plist` and verified the app too.... if anyone can help please??? Thanks in advance.

I took help from here -: http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/

Comment: show what you have done

Comment: try to post code, will help us to pin down problem

Comment: I took the code and guidance from the link given -: 
http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/
I cannot post the whole code here due to word limit but its exactly same as it is given in the link.

Comment: is app asked permission for camera ?

Comment: yes it did, after that I pressed start button but nothing happens.

Comment: post code for camera function

Comment: - (void)checkCameraPermission:(void (^)())completion {AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
[self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"Camera permissions are required for scanning QR. Please turn on Settings -> MasterpassQR Demo -> Camera"];
return;
} else if (status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
[self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"Camera permissions are restricted for scanning QR"];

Comment: return;} 
else if (status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
completion();}else if (status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
if (granted) {
completion();}
 else {[weakSelf showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"Camera permissions are required for scanning QR. Please turn on Settings -> MasterpassQR Demo -> Camera"];

Comment: Sorry I am updating in blocks....